# How to initialize an a priori unknown number of list

Tags: python, arrays, json, list, dictionary

I'm trying to re-structure a json file with python. The json is an json-array where each element is a dictionary. In these dictionaries there are a lot of repeated values for some key that is important to me, so I want to put all the other keys of every dictionary in an array for the same value of the important key, creating a json with a different structure.

Then for each different value of some key I want initialize an array. The problem is that the number of different values for this key is *a priori* unknown. An example in code that I want:

```
data = json.loads(originalJson)

# List of different authors for key ['author']
authors = []
for x in data:
    if x['author'] not in authors:
        authors.append(x['author'])

newData = []      
for author in authors:
    for x in data:
        if x['author'] == author:
  # And here is the code that initialize 
  # a different array for each author
```

P.S.: if you know a more efficient way to re-structure a json please let me a link, example or something. You will notice I'm "very beginner" with python.

EDIT: example of input and output

```
originalJson = [{ke1 : value, key2 : value, key3 : value,...},{...},....]

wantedJson = [{key1 : valueX,[{key2 : value, ...},{key3 : value,...},...]},
{key1 : valueY, [...]},{key1 : valueZ,[...]}]
```

Comment: Please post an example of input and expected matching output.

Comment: Why not use a dictionary for new_data with the author as key?

Comment: Your question is too vague. As @brunodesthuilliers said we need some sample input and output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
for x in data:
    d[x['author']].append(x)
```

Whenever an author is found, who is not in the dictionary, a new list will be created and used as the value and we append the current item to the list.

---

You can do the same, with normal dictionaries, like this

```
d = {}
for x in data:
    d.setdefault(x['author'], []).append(x)
```

---

If you want to maintain the order of authors as they are read from the file, then you can use [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), like this

```
from collections import OrderedDict
d = OrderedDict
for x in data:
    d.setdefault(x['author'], []).append(x)
```